# Bochs: display library 'nogui' not available

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, terminal-emulator, bochs

I want to open a Bochs emulator from the terminal in the terminal, as i'm working in a command line environment and cannot use GUI.

I wrote a .bochsrc config file to use but it didn't work. This is what the file looks like as of now:

```yaml
display_library: nogui
floppya: type=1_2, 1_2="bootloader.flp", status=inserted
```

I tried some options that didn't work, like `display_library: text`, and then i googled for .bochsrc files and found this file at https://github.com/lubomyr/bochs/blob/master/.bochsrc, which has a lot of commented documentation, and i used the display library option `nogui`, but it still gave me the same error:

```c
========================================================================
                       Bochs x86 Emulator 2.6.11
              Built from SVN snapshot on January 5, 2020
                Timestamp: Sun Jan  5 08:36:00 CET 2020
========================================================================
00000000000i[      ] LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH not set. using compile time default '/usr/lib/bochs/plugins'
00000000000i[      ] BXSHARE not set. using compile time default '/usr/share/bochs'
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a710930870
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_unmapped.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a710931890
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_biosdev.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a710932230
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_speaker.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a710933fb0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_extfpuirq.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a710934780
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_parallel.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a7109363e0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_serial.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a71093a7e0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_gameport.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x55a71093b010
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_iodebug.so
00000000000i[      ] reading configuration from .bochsrc
00000000000p[      ] >>PANIC<< .bochsrc:1: display library 'nogui' not available
00000000000e[SIM   ] notify called, but no bxevent_callback function is registered
00000000000e[SIM   ] notify called, but no bxevent_callback function is registered
========================================================================
Bochs is exiting with the following message:
[      ] .bochsrc:1: display library 'nogui' not available
========================================================================
00000000000i[SIM   ] quit_sim called with exit code 1
```

I also searched for tutorials and saw somebody install bochs-sdl via the command `sudo apt-get install bochs-sdl` and, knowing sdl and nogui were both listed as options, i tried downloading a specific package `bochs-nogui` that might have been missing, but there was no package with that name. For reference, i installed bochs by doing `sudo apt-get install bochs`.

**Edit:**
I looked through bochs' command line configuration interface and on the github file and there was another text option called `term`, but when i tried that one it said the open failed for the term module and that it was not found.

```c
========================================================================
                       Bochs x86 Emulator 2.6.11
              Built from SVN snapshot on January 5, 2020
                Timestamp: Sun Jan  5 08:36:00 CET 2020
========================================================================
00000000000i[      ] LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH not set. using compile time default '/usr/lib/bochs/plugins'
00000000000i[      ] BXSHARE not set. using compile time default '/usr/share/bochs'
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc18b870
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_unmapped.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc18c890
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_biosdev.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc18d230
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_speaker.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc18efb0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_extfpuirq.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc18f780
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_parallel.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc1913e0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_serial.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc1957e0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_gameport.so
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is 0x560ebc196010
00000000000i[PLUGIN] loaded plugin libbx_iodebug.so
00000000000i[      ] reading configuration from .bochsrc
00000000000i[      ] lt_dlhandle is (nil)
00000000000p[      ] >>PANIC<< dlopen failed for module 'term' (libbx_term.so): file not found
========================================================================
Event type: PANIC
Device: [      ]
Message: dlopen failed for module 'term' (libbx_term.so): file not found

A PANIC has occurred.  Do you want to:
  cont       - continue execution
  alwayscont - continue execution, and don't ask again.
               This affects only PANIC events from device [      ]
  die        - stop execution now
  abort      - dump core 
  debug      - continue and return to bochs debugger
Choose one of the actions above: [die] 
========================================================================
Bochs is exiting with the following message:
[      ] dlopen failed for module 'term' (libbx_term.so): file not found
========================================================================
00000000000i[SIM   ] quit_sim called with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you could make it work and launch it, anyway Bochs for linux doesn't work very well simulating and running your code.
Instead I use Bochs for Windows under WINE and my code runs very well.
In a command line environment you could install xorg, wine, winetricks.

Then launch xserver:

$ exec  startx

Three windows will appear, you can choose to work on anyone but do not close the others.

Then configure wine. I always emulate default "win7"

$ winecfg

You can try launching "notepad":

$ wine  notepad

If it's all right then install Bochs for Windows:

$ wine  "/home/YOUR-USER/Downloads/Bochs-win32-2.6.11.exe"

Finally you can launch "bochs.exe":

$ wine  "/home/YOUR-USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Bochs-2.6.11/bochs.exe"

The quotes are necessary. You can put this command line in a script file (xx.sh)

[See the Bochs start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMaKN.png)

Select the "Edit Options" and EDIT each one on the fly.
"Disk & Boot" is necessary at least. Then press START and voila.

I'm a 100% Debian user GUI, but I had try it yesterday on an ArchLinux pure command line environment, and works fine.

If you choose to load a "configuration file" maybe will not work. I always simulate editing from the wizard Menu.

Comment: `Three windows will appear` i am sorry but i am using a cli (command line interface) exclusively, as is stated in the first paragraph of the question. i appreciate your help, but please do read the question beforehand

Comment: in case i am wrong about something and wine creates it's own gui even if the os is configured for cli mode (which would seem weird tbh) please disregard my previous comment

Comment: It is not weird. Actually XServer (xorg) draw Xwindows in a cli (command line interface). You can try installing just "xorg" and then execute the command "startx".

Comment: There are a difference between "$ startx"  and "$ exec startx". Later when you "exit" from xwindows, if the call was "exec startx" then it will logout the user too. If the call was "startx" then the "exit" command will be simple exit.